# More elegant way of specifying a MultiMap argument?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I currently declare a `scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap` argument with a default empty map as follows:

```
case class MyClass(myMap: MultiMap[String, MyType] = new HashMap[String, Set[MyType]] with MultiMap[String, MyType]
```

This seems really verbose. All I want to do is specify a default argument of an empty `MultiMap`. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

(Scala 2.10.2)

Comment: and what's wrong with `case class MyClass(mm: MultiMap[String, MyType])`?

Comment: @AlexIv I'd like an empty MultiMap as a default arg

Comment: ...but you're right in that I can remove the Map[String, Set[MyType]] from the beginning of the type declaration. I've updated the question.

Comment: how about implicit parameter? Then you can drop default parameter and scalac will automatically insert implicit map?

Comment: @AlexIv forgive the naive question, but won't this mean I can't publicly access myMap in objects of the case class?

Comment: case class are algebraic data types so their parameters are immutable public fields. In any case they are are publicly visible

Comment: @AlexIv when I used implicit params in the case class, I found I wasn't able to access those params as fields from outside objects of the case class. I'd like this access to be available.

Comment: you did something wrong, `case class Some(implicit str: String)` you can access `str` simply calling `inst.str`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't much better, but:

```
// import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }

class MyType
type MM = MultiMap[String, MyType]
case class MyClass(myMap: MM = new HashMap[String, Set[MyType]] with MM)
```